# webpack - can't access jQuery on index.html

Tags: jquery, angular, webpack

I use angular 2 class seed, which uses webpack.

I got jQuery running successfully in my app (after the loading is done I can use $).

but now I'm trying to use jQuery at index.html, and it says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`
 - because I want to add a div in the "loading..." phase, and remove it after the first server response.

my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet"  href="index.css">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="32x32" href="/assets/icon/favicon-32x32.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="96x96" href="/assets/icon/favicon-96x96.png" type="image/png">
  <link rel="icon" sizes="16x16" href="/assets/icon/favicon-16x16.png" type="image/png">

  <title><%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %></title>

  <meta name="description" content="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>">

  <!-- base url -->
  <base href="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.baseUrl %>">



</head>

<body>

  <app>
    Loading...
  </app>

  <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.isDevServer && htmlWebpackPlugin.options.metadata.HMR !== true) { %>
  <!-- Webpack Dev Server reload -->
  <script src="/webpack-dev-server.js"></script>
  <% } %>

  <script>

       console.log($, "Jquery will be undefined.");


  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

how can I access jQuery in that "loading..." phase?

Comment: Why don't you add your `<div>` within `<app>...</app>` and let Angular remove it? Also, why would you want to use jQuery with Angular?... ;)

Comment: 1) I tried this approach - the result : the animation (the div I would like to insert) would be shown for a blink of an eye. and then when the app loads I'm loading the animation again. - it just doesn't looks so good.  I would like to put the animation, as the app loads, and keep it moving until the server responds. so it will be continuous from the start till the end.   2) I inserted jQuery to the project because my team asked me to :)  we will remove it if it wont be necessary.   Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Have to tried adding a `script` tag before the bundle?

U need to load jQuery separately from the webpack bundle. if you must.

When the app is fully loaded, you have the bundle ready and ng2 will bootstrap over the `<app>`, by that time, ur jQuery loader is irrelevant.

i would try and load the jQuery `script` in the `<head>`.

**Please Note**

This may be an anti-pattern - loading jQuery library just to implement a loader or a loading feature may cost lot more performance rather than implementing it in vanilla js.

After the app has fully loaded and your jQuery operation is done, the entire lib will have no use in your app.

Comment: Your great, It's just what I did yesterday, and came up to the same conclusions.    And even when I did loaded jquery separately from other modules,  and tried to run the animation,  it still was stuck.  - I think because the thread was busy handling the bundle and bootstrapping angular, may be I am right?      is there **any** possible way to make an animation separately ? (I've read about web workers, but it seems its more for calculations, and not for dom manipulations.)

Comment: I would go with the element.classList methods, this way you can handle your animations through CSS `@keyframes`, which leads to a clean separation of concerns.

Comment: Well, I found out that no matter what  - my animation gets stuck.   I think that when I get the vendor.js (my modules) and angular is bootstrapping the js thread is so busy it makes my animation stutter for a sec ! , If you could help me solve this I would really appreciate it.    Thing i've tried : 1) GPU - didn't made anything better.   2) Web worker - Can't effect the dom. 3) light animations (like font awesome spin) works.    but my animation is probably considered heavier.  :(   link: http://codepen.io/gviligvili/pen/EZWbEV